# jujud won't start because of different ip address

Tags: juju, openstack, virtualization

Is there anyone who can tell me how to modify both public and private IP of juju bootstrap node stored in mongodb?

I have an all in one openstack server. This week, I launched a vm named `juju-core` and installed software package `juju-core` on it. By using the command  `juju bootstrap` , I successfully got a juju bootstrap node, which is also a vm on openstack, running very well. And now I have a 
problem and don't know how to solve it. I created a snapshot of the juju bootstrap vm and named it `juju-bootstrap-snapshot`. After that, I launch a new instance, which is named `juju bootstrap-1`, from that snapshot.

In order to connect to `juju bootstrap-1` I have to login to `juju-core vm` and modify IP address of state-servers in

`/home/$user/.juju/environments/openstack.jenv`.

When I run the command `juju status` on the `juju-core vm`, there is always no response.
So I login to `juju bootstrap-1` to try finding out what happened; and I found there's no process listening on port 17070.

```
> netstat -ntulp

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6514            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      838/rsyslogd    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      970/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:37017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      932/mongod      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      932/mongod      
tcp6       0      0 :::6514                 :::*                    LISTEN      838/rsyslogd    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      970/sshd        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           587/dhclient    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15712           0.0.0.0:*                           587/dhclient    
udp6       0      0 :::52056                :::*                                587/dhclient
```

But the jujud is running

```
>ps aux | grep juju
root       932  0.6  2.1 3516932 44336 ?       Ssl  Jan15   7:08 /usr/lib/juju/bin/mongod --auth --dbpath=/var/lib/juju/db --sslOnNormalPorts --sslPEMKeyFile /var/lib/juju/server.pem --sslPEMKeyPassword xxxxxxx --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 --port 37017 --noprealloc --syslog --smallfiles --journal --keyFile /var/lib/juju/shared-secret --replSet juju --oplogSize 817<p>
root       935  0.2  0.6 426096 14032 ?        Ssl  Jan15   2:37 /var/lib/juju/tools/machine-0/jujud machine --data-dir /var/lib/juju --machine-id 0 --debug
```

I also modified `apiaddresses` in `/var/lib/juju/agents/machine-0/agent.conf` on vm `juju bootstrap-1`; just to make sure that juju end-point will be listening on `port 17070`. But there is still no process listening on `port 17070`.

By using another tool, `juju-dbinspect`, I found that both public IP and private IP of the original juju bootstrap node are stored in `mongodb`. So I try to modify related tables in `mysql` of `openstack` neutron and nova just to make sure that the new juju bootstrap node can obtain the IP of the original juju bootstrap node. After I get this done, the juju end-point started successfully and there is a service listing on `port 17070` of the new juju bootstrap node. Everything works again.

When doing jobs in openstack; creating a snapshot of a vm, launching a vm from a snapshot is very common usage. I don't know why juju bootstrap node vm won't work in such situation. Please let me know if I missed anything. According to what I have done, the new vm `juju bootstrap-1` should work very well if I can modify both public IP and private IP of the original juju bootstrap node stored in mongodb on it. But I don't know how to do it. Anyone who can tell me how to do it will be very appriciated.

Thank you, Jeff